# Firebase Hosting rewrite doesn't show SSR content on Google Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, server-side-rendering, firebase-hosting, angular-universal, google-cloud-run

In order to Server Side Render my project I have set up a docker container with Node.js.
The container is registered at Google's Container Registry and connected to a service at Cloud Run. When I use the provided Service URL the site is SSR and everything looks perfectly fine.

To connect the project with firebase I wrote this redirect:

```
"hosting": {
"public": "dist/browser",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "run": {
      "serviceId": "nest-server-ssr",
      "region": "europe-west1"
    }
  }
]
},
```

Unfortunately, when I look at the code now, it isn't rendered Serverside anymore.

Has someone encountered similar issues?

EDIT:

As Michael mentions the problem is the second index.html file. You can see that this is served. (I added a test comment to be sure)

[image]

So the solution is simply to remove your index.html file from the public directory. Thank you Michael for helping out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a guess as to what's happening)

If you have an `index.html` in your `dist/browser` folder and visit the root path for your site (`/`), the static HTML will be served instead of calling the Cloud Run service.

As you can see [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order), "exact-match" static content has a higher priority than rewrites.

To solve this, you would simply remove your `index.html` file from the public directory.

Comment: Hi Michael! 
Thank you for the comment. I have a simple Dockerfile that executes "npm run build:ssr". The command creates two directories in the dist folder. One called server (no HTML inside) the other called browser (with the HTML inside). The public folder is deleted. And the only other index.html file is the one angular created in the src folder. When I delete the index.html from angular the browser index.html can't be created anymore.

Comment: What I mean is that so long as there is an `index.html` file in the directory pointed to by `public`, that will **always** be served instead of a function rewrite. So if you want your root URL to be served by the function and not as static content, you need need to change your build to delete or rename `index.html` in the `public` folder before deploying.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Michael. You saved me a lot of time! :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add 'index.html' to the ignore list so that it will not be deployed.

```
"hosting": {
"public": "dist/browser",
"ignore": [
  "index.html",
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "run": {
      "serviceId": "nest-server-ssr",
      "region": "europe-west1"
    }
  }
]
},
```

Comment: This helped me. For some reason on the default project `firebase use default` I didn't need this, but when I added a staging project it wouldn't work. Maybe due to when the default project was created (a couple years ago at least)?